# How can I decrement these values in my firestore with loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to decrement the quantities of the `color` upon submitting the form. So, I have these forms where the user can choose a product and also enter the quantity and choose a color(s). And then also allows the user to add more products and so on.

This is what the data looks like if I'll submit it:

[image: ![enter image description here]

And these are the firestore documents for the `Shirt` and `Notebook`

[image]   [image]

How can I create a function to decrement the specific values that were in the data above upon submitting? I only tried hardcoding the document ID and then decrement it, and it does work. However, I am unsure of how to do this dynamically.

I've assumed that the `qty` is equal to 10 just to see if it really does decrement. And it does. Also, I'm not using any admin SDK.

```
const qty = 10;

  async function updateData(color) {
    const docRef = doc(db, "products", "m08YmrlFxhxLxyc3hVjT");
    await updateDoc(docRef, {
      [`colorMap.Black`]: increment(`${-qty}`),
      [`colorMap.Gold`]: increment(`${-qty}`),
    });

    const docRef2 = doc(db, "products", "nN2w57SiDovbtQ6EBzGb");
    await updateDoc(docRef2, {
      [`colorMap.green`]: increment(`${-qty}`),
      [`colorMap.red`]: increment(`${-qty}`),
    });
  }
```

This is my form:

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-nested-arrays-2-efwq6?fbclid=IwAR25MosMKxOk-Lyz23Lp7kbkuZSWaSXPSYSehOG-0L0PRhRGtQeZdzXzILk&file=/src/index.js

**index.js**
Where I submit it:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import FieldArray from "./fieldArray";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const defaultValues = {
  test: [
    {
      product: "",
      nestedArray: [{ size: "", color: "", design: "" }]
    }
  ]
};

function App() {
  const {
    control,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    getValues,
    errors,
    reset,
    setValue
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    try {
      //codes here to submit the data in the another collection
      //then a function to decrement the values.
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h1>Array of Array Fields</h1>
      <p>
        The following example demonstrate the ability of building nested array
        fields.
      </p>

      <FieldArray
        {...{ control, register, defaultValues, getValues, setValue, errors }}
      />

      <button type="button" onClick={() => reset(defaultValues)}>
        Reset
      </button>

      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      {/* <input type="submit" /> */}
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: There's plenty of code in your question. Can you just keep the part from where you are trying to decrement the values?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is the cause of the problem, but this seems wrong:

```
increment(`${-qty}`)
```

Firestore's [`increment` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#increment) takes a numerical value, and you are passing a string. The proper invocation is:

```
increment(-1 * qty)
```

Comment: Is there a way where I could loop the function `updateData`? What I did there was just hard coded the document ID of the specific product and then decrement it. Is there a way not to hard code it?

Comment: That seems unrelated to my answer. Did what I explained make sense? Did you try it? Did anything change?

Comment: yes, I did try the `increment(-1 * qty)` and it did work

Comment: Thank you, I'll post another question for my previous comment